# Android: How to round off end of progress, in a progress-bar?

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar

How do I round off the end of the progress bar. In the image below is what i currently have. As you can see the border, the start and the end is rounded. I would like to also round off where the progress ends. How can i do that?

[image]

My custom_progressbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/progressBarStrokeColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    
    <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="8dp" />
                <gradient
                    android:angle="180"
                    android:centerColor="@color/purple_700"
                    android:centerY="1.0"
                    android:endColor="#000000"
                    android:startColor="@color/red" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: try to change your Radius lto 45dp

Comment: I tried changing the radius for the background, and the progress and nothing change. Right now the corner-radius for the background and the progress is at 45dp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try with this I changed the `<clip/>` tag to `<scale/>` and I set scaleWidth to 100%:
[consult the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Scale)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <shape>

                <corners android:radius="8dp" />
                <gradient

                    android:angle="180"
                    android:centerColor="@color/purple_700"
                    android:centerY="1.0"
                    android:endColor="#000000"
                    android:startColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And this is the output:

[image]